# Passing a variable into a parameter defined by another function python

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

I am unsure of why the variable `totalspeed` variable is not being passed correctly to the function `startgame` as the `startgame` function is called after the `gettotalspeed` function.

Exerpt from call function:

```
gettotalspeed(party_ids)
NoOfEvents=0
startgame(party_ids,totalspeed,distance,NoOfEvents)
```

Functions

```
def gettotalspeed(party_ids):
    #Get selected party members IDS
    print(party_ids)
    #Obtain Speeds
    ids_string = ','.join(str(id) for id in party_ids)
    mycursor.execute("SELECT startspeed FROM characters WHERE CharID IN ({0})".format(ids_string))
    myspeeds=mycursor.fetchall()
    totalspeed=0
    for speedval in myspeeds:
        totalspeed=totalspeed + speedval[0]
    print("totalspeed is: ",totalspeed)
    return totalspeed
def startgame(party_ids,totalspeed,distance,NoOfEvents):
    #Check if game end
    print(totalspeed)
    while distance!=0:
        #Travel...
        distance=distance-totalspeed
        NoOfEvents=NoOfEvents+1
        #Generate Random Encounter
        genevent(NoOfEvents)
    return NoOfEvents
```

Error Produced:

```
NameError: name 'totalspeed' is not defined
```

Outputs (`ignoring party_ids`)

```
totalspeed is:  15
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to make totalspeed a global variable like `global totalspeed` in your gettotalspeed() function. You might also be confused about what `return` does. If you wanted to do it the "proper" way, you could do `totalspeed = gettotalspeed(party_ids)`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Whoops, we both edited at the same time and my edit ended up cutting out a chunk of your post. You might want to [edit] that back. I just meant to remove the first and last sentences.

Comment: Oh, okay. I thought maybe your edits were better than mine in some way, so I accepted it. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your problem is self-evident from the main program:

```
gettotalspeed(party_ids)
NoOfEvents=0
startgame(party_ids,totalspeed,distance,NoOfEvents)
```

Of the variables you pass to your functions, only `NoOfEvents` is defined.  `party_ids`, `totalspeed`, and `distance` have no definitions.

Work through a tutorial on Python scoping rules.  Most of all, note that a function defines a scoping block.  Variables inside the function are reclaimed when you leave the function; their names do not apply outside of that block.  Your posted program has three independent `totalspeed` variables.